# I'm having problems using a discord bot that lists players on a CS 1.6 server

Tags: discord.py

First of all, be gentle, This is my first time using python and discord.py since all I learned in school is C++ HTML and PHP

I'm trying to use a discord bot that shows details about a GoldenSrc Server (More specifically a CS 1.6 server) that I got from github.

I installed Python, PIP, discord.py and launched the bot using powershell and the following command as stated by the creator :
`python main.py`
The bot has the following command to set the ip of the server :
`$setup ip:port`

This is what I get :

```py
Logged in as: [REDACTED]#****
(Input : $setup [ip]:[port] on discord server chat)
Ignoring exception in command setup:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Discord bot\cogs\commands.py", line 44, in setup
    await Database(self).replace_db(guild_id)
  File "D:\Discord bot\cogs\database.py", line 31, in replace_db
    if row[0] != str(guild_id):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code present in main.py

```py
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

owner_id = REDACTED

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as: {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send(f'> Loaded {extension}.')

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send(f'> Unloaded {extension}.')

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.reload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send(f'> Reloaded {extension}.')

def load_cogs():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

def has_perms(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.message.author.id == owner_id:
        return True

    return False
    
load_cogs()

client.run('REDACTED')
```

commands.py :

```
# import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from cogs.query import *
from cogs.database import *
from main import has_perms

class Commands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        author = self.client.get_user(ctx.message.author.id)

        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.set_author(name='Commands:')
        embed.add_field(name='$help', value='Displays this message.', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='$setup IP:Port', value='Used to setup a source server.', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='$server', value='Displays current server information.', inline=False)

        embed2 = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.blue())
        embed2.add_field(name='To setup your server please use this format: $setup IP:Port', value='$setup 127.0.0.1:27015', inline=False)
        embed2.set_footer(text='Source Server Manager | Created by Hamzah#0017')

        await author.send(embed=embed)
        await author.send(embed=embed2)

        await ctx.send('Please check your DMs for a list of commands.')

    @commands.command()
    async def setup(self, ctx, address):
        if not has_perms(ctx):
            await ctx.send('> You must be an admin to use this command.')
            return

        if "." not in address or ":" not in address:
            await ctx.send('> The IP/Port was formatted incorrectly, e.g. 127.0.0.1:27015')
            return

        guild_id = ctx.message.author.guild.id

        await Database(self).replace_db(guild_id)
        await Database(self).write_db(guild_id, address)

        await ctx.send('Your server has been added to the database, use the $server command to view server information.')

    @commands.command()
    async def server(self, ctx):
        check = str(ctx.message.channel.type)
        if check == 'private':
            return False

        address = (await Database(self).read_db())[0][1]
        server_info = await Query(self).get_server_info(address)

        server_embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.blue())
        server_embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1852/PNG/512/iconfinder-server-4417119_116634.png')
        server_embed.set_author(name=server_info[2])
        server_embed.add_field(name='IP Address:', value=address)
        server_embed.add_field(name='Players:', value=str(server_info[0]) + '/' + str(server_info[1]), inline=False)
        server_embed.add_field(name='Map:', value=server_info[3], inline=False)
        server_embed.set_footer(text='Source Server Manager | Created by Hamzah#0017')

        await ctx.send(embed=server_embed)

        if server_info[0] == 0:
            return

        try:
            player_info = await Query(self).get_players(address)

            player_embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Color.blue())
            player_embed.set_author(name='Online Players:')

            for i in range(0, server_info[0]):
                player_embed.add_field(name=player_info[0][i], value=str(player_info[1][i]) + ' minutes')
            
            await ctx.send(embed=player_embed)

        except:
            await ctx.send('> I was unable to print the player list, this could be due to weird characters in names.')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Commands(client))
```

database.py

```
  
import discord, csv
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

class Database(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    async def read_db(self):
        lines = list()

        with open('database.csv', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                lines.append(row)

        return lines

    async def write_db(self, guild_id, address):
        with open('database.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([guild_id, address])

    async def replace_db(self, guild_id):
        lines = list()

        with open('database.csv', 'r') as inp:
            for row in csv.reader(inp):
                if row[0] != str(guild_id):
                    lines.append(row)

        with open('database.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            for x in range(0, len(lines)):
                writer.writerow([lines[x][0]])

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Database(client))
```

query.py

```
import discord, valve.source.a2s
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

class Query(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    async def get_server_info(self, address):
        address = address.split(':')[0], int(address.split(':')[1])
        info = list()

        with valve.source.a2s.ServerQuerier(address) as server:
            info.append(server.info()['player_count'])
            info.append(server.info()['max_players'])
            info.append(server.info()['server_name'])
            info.append(server.info()['map'])
            info.append(server.info()['game'])

        return info

    async def get_players(self, address):
        address = address.split(':')[0], int(address.split(':')[1])
        player_list, time_online = [], []

        with valve.source.a2s.ServerQuerier(address) as query:
            for player in query.players()['players']:
                player_list.append("{name}".format(**player))
                time_online.append(round(float("{duration}".format(**player)) / 60))

        return player_list, time_online

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Query(client))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please post the relevant code? The error message displays a different command, which is not present here.

Comment: i have added all the .py files from the folder

Comment: the D:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py comes from discord.py

Comment: @Rosco The `D:\Discord bot\cogs\commands.py` and `D:\Discord bot\cogs\database.py` come from your own code which is the main cause. the discord.py core is just there because discord.py calls your function when someone uses that command

Comment: `row` is most likely empty, idk what your csv library is but I guess it doesn't filter out empty lines? or something is wrong with the lib, not really a discord.py *specific* issue

Comment: Adding your *whole* project into a question is simply not smart. You can reduce the code to one function.